# Android Fused Location API provides strange results

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I'm developing an android app and getting **pretty strange results with the new Google Fused Location API**.
I'm currently inside a building and Google maps and my application show that **I'm ~200 meters away from my real location**.  However, I can see that **location accuracy is 10 meters**, no matter whether the GPS is turned on or off. In fact the accuracy is 60-70m in the beginning and reaches 10.0 meters in ~1 minute.
Old Location Listener API shows the same location and accuracy ~60-70 meters.
The situation is the same on several android devices with different android versions.
In my app I need reliable results (by reliability I mean that accuracy can be 200 meters if GPS is off but not as I described).
What can I do about that?